# Can't send Notifications using C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, notifications, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to send a notification (not app requests) to registered users, server-side using the C# Facebook SDK.  I actually get a success message, but no notification is sent.  Our app is not in sandbox and has canvas enabled.  The code below show attempts to send both notifications and app requests--the notifications do nothing, but the app request works:

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "MY_APP_KEY",
            client_secret = "MY_SECRET",
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
        fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;

        dynamic nparams = new ExpandoObject();
        nparams.template = "Hello from my app!";
        nparams.href = "Home";

        dynamic requestParams = new ExpandoObject();
        requestParams.message = "Hi there";
        requestParams.title = "Please use this awesome app";

        foreach (string facebookID in facebookIDs)
        {
            // This returns success:true, but doesn't actually do anything
            var postResult = fb.Post(facebookID + "/notifications", nparams);

            // This works and shows a request in the app center
            var postResult2 = fb.Post(facebookID + "/apprequests", requestParams);
        }
```

The fact that apprequests send here tells me the access token is ok, so why don't notifications work?  We really need to do this server-side--has anyone been able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from facebook on this . . . basically, that this feature is in beta and it may just not work, despite giving Success responses

Answer (score 0):

Good snippet Anthony.  Appears to be working consistently now.  +1 for your attempt.

PS:  In case anyone stumbles upon this code, "facebookID"  is a numeric Id and can be derived using the following link  http://findmyfacebookid.com/